# Numpy Permutations of a 3D Matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, matrix, tuples

I've got a `n x n x 2` matrix which I want to find all possible permutations of without changing the order of elements in the 3rd dimension.
For example, if my matrix was `2 x 2 x 2` and had the following values:

```
[[[1,2], [3,4]],  
  [5,6], [7,8]]
```

Then possible permutations would be:

```
[[[1,2], [3,4]],  
  [7,8], [5,6]]   

[[[3,4], [1,2]],  
  [5,6], [7,8]]   

[[[1,2], [7,8]],  
  [5,6], [3,4]]
```

etc.

In other words, I want to treat the tuples as single values when finding the permutations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

arr = np.array([[[1,2], [3,4]],
                [[5,6], [7,8]]])

for p in itertools.permutations(arr.reshape(-1, 2)):
    print(np.array(p).reshape(arr.shape))
```